# How Can I Configure Selenium grid to test website in parallel?

Tags: selenium

I want to use selenium grid for my web page testing. I have successfully installed the demo of selenium grid on my PC and it is running fine.
I have followed  [this link](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/run_the_demo.html) to install and run the selenium grid demo.

I am trying to code a java program using selenium rc which can run with selenium grid for testing the web site, but I am not getting how does I make change on the selenium grid existing demo so that it will work for my web test.

Can some body provide me any link/example so that I will do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of Selenium Grid is that you will either need a way to run your tests in parallel or have multiple processes firing requests to the Remote Controls.

If you're using JUnit, there's a [post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423627/running-junit-tests-in-parallel) that has a number of recommendations for parallelization.

There's actually an example in the Selenium Grid demo as well. It uses TestNG's built-in multi-threading capability. If you write your test harness in TestNG, that should simplify the process of following the pattern in the demo build file.